# Angular Kendo UI - npm packages deleted while installing kendo-angular-dateinputs

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I already have kendo-angular-layout package. I wanted to install kendo-angular-dateinputs for another issue. But when i do npm install @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs, some of the old packages are being deleted(like ng-drag-drop, kendo-angular-layout). why is this happening.Can anyone help me here?

Comment: did you check in package.json whether the dev dependencies are there ?

Comment: yes they're all there @MBalajivaishnav

Comment: then give a try like this, add the progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs dependencies in package.json and use npm install --save

Comment: I installed  progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs . Package json is updated with the new entry. i deleted my node modules and did npm install again.. it works.. dont know why the intitial issue happened

Comment: glad that it works